# instanceof returns false in jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, instanceof, amazon-neptune

I have problem with `instanceof` in java.
For clarification, I use `aws-neptune-jdbc` drive for connection to janusgraph server.

I create `GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0` which is obviously instance of `MessageSerializer`. After that i put serializer in `Properties`. And even in properties this object in instance of `MessageSerializer`.

Code for this part:

```
GraphSONMapper.Builder builder = GraphSONMapper.build().addRegistry(JanusGraphIoRegistry.getInstance());
GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0 serializer = new GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0(builder);
System.out.println(String.format("Serializer: %s", serializer));
System.out.println(String.format("Name of serializer class: %s", serializer.getClass().getName()));
System.out.println(String.format("Serializer is instance of MessageSerializer: %s", serializer instanceof MessageSerializer));
properties.put("serializer", serializer);
System.out.println(String.format("Serializer in properties: %s", properties.get("serializer")));
System.out.println(String.format("Serializer in properties is instance of MessageSerializer: %s", properties.get("serializer") instanceof MessageSerializer));
```

And output for this part:

```
Serializer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0@4d49af10
Name of serializer class: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0
Serializer is instance of MessageSerializer: true
Serializer in properties: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0@4d49af10
Serializer in properties is instance of MessageSerializer: true
```

But in driver, I add some info in log, I can see, that something, that is in map under key `serializer`, is not a `MessageSerializer` and `GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0`, but has class name `GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0`

My code with logger in jdbc for this part

```
LOGGER.info(String.format("Creating cluster with serializer: %s", properties.get(GremlinConnectionProperties.SERIALIZER_KEY)));
LOGGER.info(String.format("Serializer is null?: %s", properties.get(GremlinConnectionProperties.SERIALIZER_KEY) == null));
LOGGER.info(String.format("Class of serializer is: %s", properties.get(GremlinConnectionProperties.SERIALIZER_KEY).getClass().getName()));
LOGGER.info(String.format("Serializer is GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0?: %s", properties.get(GremlinConnectionProperties.SERIALIZER_KEY) instanceof GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0));
LOGGER.info(String.format("Serializer is MessageSerializer?: %s", properties.get(GremlinConnectionProperties.SERIALIZER_KEY) instanceof MessageSerializer));
```

And output for this part

```
378 [main] INFO software.aws.neptune.gremlin.GremlinQueryExecutor - Creating cluster with serializer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0@4d49af10
379 [main] INFO software.aws.neptune.gremlin.GremlinQueryExecutor - Serializer is null?: false
379 [main] INFO software.aws.neptune.gremlin.GremlinQueryExecutor - Class of serializer is: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0
380 [main] INFO software.aws.neptune.gremlin.GremlinQueryExecutor - Serializer is GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0?: false
380 [main] INFO software.aws.neptune.gremlin.GremlinQueryExecutor - Serializer is MessageSerializer?: false
```

Why is that? I need it to be true. I have same version of `gremlin-driver` in my script and `aws-neptune-jdbc`, which is 3.5.3. In github `aws-neptune-jdbc` right now have gremlin version 3.4.8, but I change it for myself.

**P.S.** Forgot to mention, my version of java is `openjdk version "1.8.0_342"`

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the problem. `aws-neptune-jdbc-driver` has in `build.gradle` this line, when you gather everything in signle jar file.

```
relocate 'org.apache.tinkerpop', 'shadow.org.apache.tinkerpop'
```

Because of it, `MessageSerializer` in driver is `shadow.org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.MessageSerializer`, and `MessageSerializer` in my script is just `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.MessageSerializer` and this is indeed different classes.
If I understand correctly, only fix for this is juts remove this line from build.gradle?